# Using a common static value to programatically identify classes

Tags: .net, static-members

In a reporting application, I have a number of different types of graphs, each of which is output with code in a specific class. Eg. clsPieChart, clsBarChart, etc. Each of those is derived from a base class, clsChartBase.

Now, the report can be put together dynamically, so there is a string ID code in the database for each type of chart, eg. "pie", "bar", etc.

My solution has been to use a common static variable in each class to match it up with the database code, eg:

```
Class clsPieChart
  Inherits clsChartBase
  Public ReadOnly Shared _ChartID As String = "pie" ' Each class has one of these.
```

This is how I can identify which class needs to be instantiated to handle that part of the report. Is this a reasonable approach, or is there a better way to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having a `Dictionary(Of String, Type)` instead - that keeps all the information in a single place, and means you can perform the mapping programmatically. You could make another mapping in the other direction as well, of course - and that can be autogenerated from the first (e.g. using `ToDictionary()` in LINQ).

I'd also strongly advise you to get rid of the `cls` prefix for your class names - it's worth reading [Microsoft's naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) so that your code is idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah The Hungarian is just a byproduct of my working with javascript, php, etc in text editors. Tough habit to break.

Comment: @ingredient_15939: It's well worth trying to break it. Following the conventions of the language you're working in is crucial to writing code which looks and feels right to others.

Comment: True. :) Even with a dictionary, the class still needs the static string though, yes? Or are you saying I don't need it with that method?

Comment: @ingredient_15939: No, there's no need for a static string variable here. What benefit do you think it would have?

Comment: Sorry, I'm being a dill.. the string in the dictionary is all I need. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could do `TypeOf obj Is YourClass` to identify the class of your object. You will get rid of keeping a shared variable within the class.

Comment: Thanks, but there's no object at that point, there's only the text field from the database, which I need to compare with something before instantiating the corresponding class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that correctly. At some point you must traverse through a decision tree to create an object of the corresponding class. If you have a db field that lets you decide the chart class, then Jon's method of creating a `Dictionary(Of String, Type)` is the best for you. That way, you can create a one-liner that will give you the corresponding type when you pass the class identifier (e.g. "pie") as key to it.

Comment: Yep that's correct. Jon's solution is neat and easily understandable to another reader what's going on when they see the assignments in one place.